# PHP: using SQL result in a loop without re-executing query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, for-loop, while-loop

I am trying to add 3 combo boxes which all display the exact same information that comes from my MySQL db. It seems like the code I wrote makes the entire page wait until all 3 combo boxes are populated, before continuing.

```
<?
$query = "Select * from tblWriters order by surname";

for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {

    $result = mysql_query($query);

    echo "<tr><td>Writer".$i." *</td><td>";
    echo "<select name='txtWriter".$i."' style='width: 200px;'>";
    echo "<option value ='' selected='selected'></option>";

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
         echo "<option value ='" . $row['id'] . "'> " . $row['surname'] . ", " . $row['name'] . "</option>";
    }

    echo "</select><td></tr>";
}
?>
```

I would like to optimize this piece of code, so the query will not be executed 3 times, as I believe this is where the page slows down.

If I put

> $result = mysql_query($query);

outside of the for loop, the 2nd and 3rd combo box do not populate. I tried looking into resetting the pointer of the result, but I can't seem to figure out how that works.

Also, is there a way I can reuse the while loop, so I don't have to execute it 3 times?

Can someone point me in the right direction? 
I'm pretty new to PHP and trying to learn on my own. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you move your mysql_query() out of the loop again, you can reset your mysql-result-pointer by using [mysql_data_seek()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-data-seek.php) at the beginning or end of your loop.

This will result in:

```
 mysql_query($query);
 for($i=1;$i<=3;$i++);
 {
     mysql_data_seek(0); // reset datapointer

     // output querydata
 }
```

I'm obliged however to point out that the mysql-extension is deprecated by now and you should use [mysqli](http://www.php.net/mysqli) or [pdo](http://www.php.net/pdo) for new projects and code.

Comment: Many thanks! This was what I was looking for. Also thanks for the tip. I'll look into that!

Answer (score 0):

Cache the query result in an array, then generate your markup:

```
$query = "Select * from tblWriters order by surname";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$data = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $data[] = $row;
}

for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {

    echo "<tr><td>Writer".$i." *</td><td>";
    echo "<select name='txtWriter".$i."' style='width: 200px;'>";
    echo "<option value ='' selected='selected'></option>";
    foreach ($data as $row) {
       echo "<option value ='" . $row['id'] . "'> " . $row['surname'] . 
            ", " .   $row['name'] . "</option>";        
    }

    echo "</select><td></tr>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works too, although it doesn't seem to improve performance. Would upvote, but don't have enough reputation yet.